# GridView Making a single Edit Item Template take the entire row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've got this gridview. The gridview uses TemplateFields as the number of fields in the database's table. What I do next is use an ItemTemplate to present the correct column info.

Now, problems rise when the user click's Edit. Since I can only use EditItemTemplate to edit I am resulted with a control in each column. What I really want is to have a single row with no columns so I can easily style the edit mode (having a table with a different layout for example).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will have to create your own specialized class that inherits from GridView and does its own rendering to accomplish this.

You might hack some workaround though... such as manually editing the rendered HTML output or DOM.